# SwiftUI TextField onChange not triggered

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

New to SwiftUI and trying to figure something out.
I'm implementing a barcode scanner, which consists of a **TextField**, **Button** and **CameraView**.
**CameraView** will scan a barcode, display the serial number in the **TextField**, and the **Button** will use the serial number to pair a bluetooth device.

So now in my SwiftUI class, I have my UI setup like so:

```
struct BTLEConnectionView: View {
    @ObservedObject var bluetoothConnectorViewModel: BluetoothConnectorViewModel
    @ObservedObject var barcodeScannerViewModel = BarcodeScannerViewModel()
    @Binding var deviceID: String

    @State private var serialNumber: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           HStack {
               DeviceIDTextField(deviceID: $deviceID, serialNumber: $serialNumber, viewModel: barcodeScannerViewModel)
            
               PairButton(bluetoothConnectorViewModel: bluetoothConnectorViewModel, barcodeScannerViewModel: barcodeScannerViewModel, serialNumber: $serialNumber)
           }
           .padding()
    
           BarcodeScannerView(barscannerViewModel: barcodeScannerViewModel)
       }
   }
}

struct DeviceIDTextField: View {
   @Binding var deviceID: String
   @Binding var serialNumber: String
   @ObservedObject var viewModel: BarcodeScannerViewModel

   var body: some View {
       let serialNumberBinding = Binding<String>(
           get: { viewModel.barcodeString.isEmpty ? serialNumber : viewModel.barcodeString },
           set: { serialNumber = viewModel.barcodeString.isEmpty ? $0 : viewModel.barcodeString }
       )
    
       TextField(NSLocalizedString("textfield.hint.device.id", comment: ""), text: serialNumberBinding)
           .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
           .onChange(of: serialNumber, perform: { value in
               serialNumber = value
           })
   }

   private func textFieldChanged(_ text: String) {
       print(text)
   }
}

struct PairButton: View {
   @ObservedObject var bluetoothConnectorViewModel: BluetoothConnectorViewModel
   @ObservedObject var barcodeScannerViewModel: BarcodeScannerViewModel
   @Binding var serialNumber: String

   var body: some View {
       Button(action: {
           withAnimation {
               bluetoothConnectorViewModel.connectBluetoothLowEnergyDevice(deviceID: serialNumber)
           }
       }) {
           ButtonText(text: NSLocalizedString("button.text.pair", comment: ""))
       }
   }
}
```

So basically I want to make it so:
If user scans barcode, the serial is added to the textfield, press pair button to use that serial and call the method and pass in the serial number.
If user deletes the prepopulated serial, enters their own, it should update the textfield, and pressing the button should use the new serial number.

Right now when I scan a barcode, it populates the text field, however the onChange callback isn't picked up until I actually type in the TextField, so the result is never set for the method call.

Any help with this would be great, hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a binding with a custom closure, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var location: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        let binding = Binding<String>(get: {
            self.location
        }, set: {
            self.location = $0
            // do whatever you want here
        })

        return VStack {
            Text("Current location: \(location)")
            TextField("Search Location", text: binding)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, however I don't think it solves the issue I am asking. Right now in the set
                self.serialNumber = $0
                serialNumber = viewModel.barcodeString.isEmpty ? $0 : viewModel.barcodeString
doesn't work. 
I need to set it to whatever the viewModel has, if the user types, remove the viewModel string and use whatever is being typed

Comment: When the screen is opened the TextField shows the hint text. If the user scans a barcode, it should get populated in the TextField, which right now it doesn't. The viewModel contains the scanned value which is fine, however I don't know how to make it use that in the TextField correctly